# How to print SSRS report on click of a button in Chrome/Edge browsers

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, printing, report

Since print button is not supported in Chrome/Edge browsers for SSRS reports, I am trying to create my own print button, where it opens up the print dialog on click of that button.

Tried many solutions found in SO and CodeProject but no luck.

Here is my below code where the report is being created as PDF and stored locally, but while giving it for print, the browser console gives me the error: *"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/printer/Print.pdf"* Note: I have given full access to *'Everyone'* on this folder in C: drive

Here is my html code for the button:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <iframe id="frmPrint" name="IframeName" width="500" height="200" runat="server" style="display: none"></iframe>
            
            <div style="margin: 10px">
                <asp:Button ID="BtnPrint" float="right" runat="server" OnClick="BtnPrint_Click" Text="Print Report" />
            </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS function:

```
printReport = function () {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('frmPrint');
            iframe.src = "C:\\printer\\Print.pdf"; 
            if (iframe.src) {
                var frm = iframe.contentWindow;
                frm.focus();
                frm.print();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Here is the Server side button click event:

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;
            byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\printer\\Print.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
//Attach pdf to the iframe
            frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = "C:\\printer\\Print.pdf";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "printReport", "printReport();", true);
        }
```

Tried updating the iFrame src dynamically from button click event with the PDF file path but in JS function, I am getting empty iFrame src, so just for testing, I am hardcoding the iFrame src in JS function.

Please help!

Comment: Check if using the format parameter in the URL helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you please let me know which URL you are referring to in my case?

Comment: There is an example in the link using the rs:Format=PDF.